# Sqlite3 Vs web2py DAL

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I have been working with sqlite DB for some time but want to integrate my codes to web2py esp. DAL. How do I  rewrite such a code to web2py DAL code?

```
      name = input ('Please Type your Question:  ').lower().split()  
      name2 = name[:]
      import sqlite3
      for item in name2:#break                
         conn = sqlite3.connect("foods.db")
         cursor = conn.cursor()           
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO INPUT33 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name2,))      
         cursor.execute("select MAX(rowid) from [input33];")
         conn.commit()      
         for rowid in cursor:break         
         for elem in rowid:
            m = elem            
            print(m)
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM INPUT33 (NAME) WHERE NAME = name")
```

Comment: You should consider providing another code snippet that is more clear to your intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite understand the question so I would like to apologize in advance for any misunderstanding.

Web2py is a Web [MVC framework](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/01/introduction#Model-View-Controller) and you should follow that pattern while designing your application. Having that in mind, using a console-related function like `input` makes no sense. Also, you shouldn't use the same component to extract user interaction related data and deal with database connection and data access/manipulation.

If your intent is to simply convert your code snippet that used sqlite3 module into using [pyDAL](https://github.com/web2py/pydal) you just need to install it `pip install pydal` and change your code to something like

```
#Do your imports
from pydal import DAL, Field

#  connect to your database
db = DAL('sqlite://foods.db')
# define your table model and table fields
db.define_table('input33', Field('NAME'))

# perform an insert into input database
db.input33.insert(name=name2)
# every insert/delete/update needs your to commit to your changes
db.commit()
```

A full documentation can be found [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer)